# Sql server management studio does not allow to edit a value of table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Using c# code, I have converted my byte array to a string, and then stored into a sql table using Entity framework. No issues until here.

But, if I try to see value stored inside a table using 'select' command in MSSql Server Management studio, it does show blank value in that column. If I query Len(MyColumn) then it shows a valid length.

Why I am unable see value stored?

**Update**:
It shows a value when I right click on table -> Edit top 200 rows. But, as soon as I click on that cell, value disappears. I am using Sql server 2005.

Comment: What is your select command?

Comment: what is the datatype, and what is the expected result?

Comment: What is the datatype of that column? is it varchar?

Comment: Datatype is nvarchar(1024). 'select mycolumn from mytable' is the command.

Comment: What do you get if you try to read the value using EF? I'm guessing it's just an encoding mismatch of some kind, but without seeing your C# code and an idea of what byte values you're passing in, it's hard to know.

Comment: What data are you storing in it?  If they are unprintable characters (tabs, etc) then you won't see anything in management studio.  Basically anything less than chr(32)

Comment: May be in byte array there is code 0 or something like that which said string that there is end of string?

Comment: if you are using SQL Server Management Studio, what happens if you right click on the table and click Show Top 1000 Rows or Edit Top 200 Rows? do you see the data?

Comment: Could you please give us the query that creates the table? Then we will see if we can reproduce it in our machines.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
 [rownum] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [orderid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 [message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ordertype] [int] NULL,
 [createdon] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_mytable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [rownum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_mytable_createdon]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdon]
GO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have converted my byte array to a string

If you did something like `message= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray)` you likely got unprintable characters. A leading `\0` can cause your string to not print. This is the wrong way to handle binary data in a SQL database.

The correct way to handle this is one of the following options (in order of preference)

1. Store the data as a `varbinary` not a `nvarchar` this lets you store the `byte[]` directly with EF without doing any conversion at all.
2. Encode the data correctly

   1. Using Base64 encoding via `message= Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArray)` and `myByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(message)`
   2. Using hexadecimal, [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) makes it very easy to go to and from hexadecimal strings.

Comment: You are correct, I was using Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray) earlier. Thank you.